# Computing all possible conformal factors on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

> **Proposition to prove**. Let $\tau\colon \mathbb S^n\to \mathbb S^n$ be a conformal map, meaning that $\tau^\star g= \Lambda^2 g$ for a scalar field $\Lambda$. (Here $g$ denotes the standard metric tensor on $\mathbb S^n$). Then there exists $\theta\in\mathbb R^{n+1}, |\theta|<1$ such that $$\Lambda(\omega)=(1-\theta\cdot \omega)^{-1},\qquad \forall \omega\in \mathbb S^n.$$

I have found this statement in some sources; for example, in [this paper of Chen-Frank-Weth](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5666), pag.7, "since the Jacobian determinant...", without proof.

Can you show me a proof, or point me in the right direction in the literature?

Comment: $S^n$ with one point removed is conformal to ${\mathbb R}^n$. So the following should be relevant:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)

Comment: @YuDing: It surely is relevant, thanks. Actually, I think I found the answer to the present question in [this book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Modern_Geometry_Methods_and_Applications.html?id=FC0QFlx12pwC&redir_esc=y) (Dubovin-Fomenko-Novikov volume 1, theorem 15.3, pag. 143). It is based on the computation of the conformal transformations of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, that is, the theorem of Liouville you mention.

Answer (score 1):

I can prove something close to the statement in the question for 2d case. Let me know if there is anything wrong!

We want to consider automorphisms of $CP^1\cong \mathbb{S}^2$. The canonical coordinate of $CP^1$ is related to the spherical coordinate through the stereographic projection:
$$
z = \cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i\phi},
$$
It follows that ([Stereographic projection is conformal --- from the line element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920691/stereographic-projection-is-conformal-from-the-line-element))
$$
g =  d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2
$$
$$
= \frac{4dzd\overline{z}}{(1+|z|^2)^2},
$$

The automorphisms of $CP^1$ are Möbius transformations, which can be generated by

$$
z \rightarrow az + b, \quad z \rightarrow \frac{1}{z},
$$
where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$. But
$$
\frac{4d\frac{1}{z}d\frac{1}{\overline{z}}}{(1 + |\frac{1}{z}|^2)^2} = \frac{4dzd\overline{z}}{(1+|z|^2)^2}
$$
so the metric is invariant under the inverse operation, we only need to consider translation and scaling. Continuing with the transformation $z \rightarrow az + b$,
$$
\frac{4|a|^2dzd\overline{z}}{(1 + |az+b|^2)^2} = \frac{|a|^2(1+|z|^2)^2}{(1 + |az + b|^2)^2} \cdot g,
$$
So the conformal factor
$$
\Lambda = \frac{|a|^2(1+|z|^2)^2}{(1 + |az + b|^2)^2}\\
= \frac{|a|^2}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)(1 + |a\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)e^{i\phi} + b|^2)^2},
$$

Denote $\omega = \begin{pmatrix}\sin\theta\cos\phi\\\sin\theta\sin\phi\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$ the Cartesian coordinate of a point on the sphere, we can rewrite the expression above as
$$
\Lambda(\omega) = \frac{1}{(A + \theta^T\omega)^2},
$$
where
$$
A = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \frac{1+|b|^2}{|a|^2}),
$$
$$
\theta_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{a} + \frac{\overline{b}}{\overline{a}}\right), \quad \theta_2 = \frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{\overline{b}}{\overline{a}}-\frac{b}{a} \right), \quad \theta_3 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{1 + |b|^2}{|a|^2}\right).
$$

Comment: I have not checked the details and I cannot right now, but I am sure this is the way to go. The key step here is that the automorphisms of $CP^1$ are the Möbius transformations. Have you got an idea of how to prove this? Because I think that an appropriate generalization of this must be true in higher dimension as well. (Thank you very much for your interest in my question).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Oh, it's quite well-known in complex analysis. You can see section 8.5 in https://math.stanford.edu/~eliash/Public/117-2024/116-117text-2024.pdf. Basically you just need to "projectivize" the linear transformation in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Comment: Hey Max, sorry for coming here only now and then. You clearly solved the case of $\mathbb S^2$. Great. Now, Yuval mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195198/computing-all-possible-conformal-factors-on-the-sphere/4878786?noredirect=1#comment6576026_3195198) a Liouville theorem for conformal maps of $\mathbb R^d$ with $d>2$. Since $\mathbb R^d$ is conformal to $\mathbb S^d\setminus\{N\}$, where $N$ is a point, that should be enough to conclude the general $d$ case as well.